# How to catch callback in Configuration class when servlet is destroyed in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am using a 3rd party API which has two static functions:

```
Manager.start()
Manager.stop()
```

I created a spring `Configuration` class and corresponding enable annotation as following:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(ManagerConfiguration.class)
@Documented
public @interface ManagerEnable {
}

@Configuration
public class ManagerConfiguration {
    static {
        Manager.start();
    }

    // todo: call Manager.stop() when servlet is destroyed
}
```

Users/clients can simple add `@ManagerEnable` to their `Configuration` class and everything works out of the box.

I want to catch a callback when the host servlet is destroyed, so I can call `Manager.stop()`. How can I do this in `ManagerConfiguration`?

Note that this must be done in code, I don't want to force the users/clients to alter their `web.xml` to register a custom `ServletContextListener`. They should stick with adding `@ManagerEnable` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the spring version you are having in project, you can achieve it this way..

Spring 4.2+

```
class Foo {
    @EventListener
    public bar(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Spring <4.2

```
class Foo implements ApplicationListener<ContextStoppedEvent> {
    void onApplicationEvent(ContextStoppedEvent event);
}
```

In your case, I would resign from "static" approach and use ContextRefreshedEvent event.

Used classes:

```
@EventListener (org.springframework.context.event)
ContextClosedEvent (org.springframework.context.event)
ContextRefreshedEvent (org.springframework.context.event)
ContextStoppedEvent (org.springframework.context.event)
ContextStartedEvent (org.springframework.context.event)
ApplicationListener (org.springframework.context)
```

Read more on that here:
    https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2

Hope it helps.

Comment: Relation question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134189/spring-what-is-difference-between-contextrefreshedevent-contextstartedevent